# A "pad" for note-taking, primarily

Tags: laptop, pc, tablet, touchpad, detachable

To prepare for college, I'm looking for a 2-in-1/tablet that will mainly serve as a notebook to write on. The device must:

- Have a (secured) pen/stylus. A full-sized pen is preferred to a thin, tiny stylus. As I may write a lot, this need to feel as "real" and comfortable an experience as possible.
- Support the use of open source note taking software. I do wish to incorporate a few features, such as spaced repetition reminders, into the app.

Other desired features:

- Big, clear screen. A4-paper-sized or more, if possible.
- The ability to quickly access internet and do internet stuff. Also the ability to easily organize my notes, but I guess they're on the software part?

Things I like, but not really important:

- Cheap. I don't have a specific budget, though.
- Good build, battery lasts long.

Thanks! Since I know next to nothing in this field, I'm open to any kind of device and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [XP-Pen Deco Pro MW](https://www.xp-pen.com/store/buy/deco-pro-sw-mw.html) ($97) and a [refurbished Galaxy Note 9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089HNHZ17) ($173).
I leave the Deco at my desk and bring the phone with me everywhere.

If you want something fills all those requirements, you will have to weed through the mediocre tablets like [PicassoTab](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08LPFBPSC) ($220), or go full Surface Pro / iPad Pro (>$1000).

Comment: The only problem with the iPad idea is that that one does not support self-compiled software. If you want that you really need Android and there is no other route that I know of except a 2in1